# V sit Vs L sit: Muscles involved

Tags: muscle

I would like to know the muscles that are involved while doing a V sit Vs doing L sit. Is one a progression over the other?

Trying V sit for just 15 seconds cause my quads to ache. Is that a weakness exposed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **L-sit is the progression towards [V-sit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkKmG.jpg)**, finishing with [Manna](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40xmV.jpg), which is an advanced-level gymnastics skill (in [this chart](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArzTY8Rx2z1DdDZlaUVxa1NISlQ0RVpMYVlRaklJelE#gid=0) of exercises taken from [Overcoming Gravity](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1467933120), there are only a few skills which are rated harder than the Manna -- L-sit is a "level 3" skill, V-sit is 6 and Manna is a whooping 13).

**Leg cramps are normal** during L-sit/V-sit work, they should get better with time. It's not a weakness.