# What muscles are involved in the downward movement of the v-sit?

Tags: exercise, muscle, bodyweight-exercises, abdominals, exercise-technique

Can you help me with the muscles involved in the downward movement of the [V sit](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/14579/7091)?

Downward would be eccentric but what muscles are the primary movers?

Answer (score 2):

The muscles used during both directions are the same, just in the opposite order of intensity.

So with V-sit in general, the muscles used are the rectus abdominis, obliques and hip flexors.

Secondary movers are triceps and forearms due simply to the fact that they are the muscles that support the weight of your body during the movement.

Comment: Would the erector spinae muscles be used at any time?  Up or down?